# Extract time from a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm new to javaScript and while working on a simple project i came across this problem. I have a string,

```
var str = "11 hrs and 34 mins";
```

and I want to only time in a time format like 11:34

so what i'm doing now is something like this

```
var str = "11 hrs and 34 mins";
var time="";
var parts=str.split(" ");
for(var i=0;i<parts.length;i++){
    if(parseInt((parts[i].trim()), 10)){
        time+=parts[i]+" ";
    }   
}
console.log(time);
```

Is there a better way of doing this with external libraries or pure javaScript. 
Can someome help me with that.

Comment: could you please give me an example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use regular expression to match digits `^([0-1][1-9]|[2][1-3]).+([0-5][0-9]).+` with exact times (0-23 hours and minutes 0-59):

```js
var str = "11 hrs and 34 mins";
var time="";
var parts=str.match(/^([0-1][1-9]|[2][1-3]).+([0-5][0-9]).+/);

document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = parts[1] + " : " + parts[2];

console.log(parts[1] + " : " + parts[2]);
```

```html
<span id="res"></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Regex (adjust it to your needs):

```
(\d+)([a-zA-Z\s])+(\d+)
```

Group number 1 and 3 will be the numbers
[Example](https://regex101.com/r/dH6zY8/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex to extract the time values

```
/(\d+).+(\d+).+/
```

Example:

```
'11 hrs and 34 mins'.replace(/(\d+).+(\d+).+/, '$1:$2')
```

Result: '11:34'

Or you can use an external libary, like [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
"11 hrs and 34 mins".replace(/.*?(\d+)\s*hrs.*?(\d+)\s*min.*/,"$1:$2")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var str = "11 hrs and 34 mins";
var time= str.match(/\d+/g);
time = time.join(':');
console.log(time);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using regex. More info [here](http://eloquentjavascript.net/09_regexp.html)

```
var timePattern = /\b\d+\b/g;
var extractedTime = "11 hrs and 34 mins".match(timePattern)
```

extracted time should have these values ["11", "34"] so you split this array already to obtain the hours and mins and put them up together.